# No sound capture in JavaFX applet started from Safari browser on Mac

Tags: java, macos, safari, javafx, applet

I use JavaFX applet that records a sound from MIC using `javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem` API. Applet is started from browser using `dtjava.js`. On all platforms it works fine, except Safari on Mac, it loads, but it has no access to built-in microphone.
Here some diagnostic code output:

```
public static String mixerInfo() {
        final Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
        return "Mixer data: " + Arrays.toString(mixerInfo);
    }
```

Output for Chrome:

```
Mixer data: [Default Audio Device, version Unknown Version, Built-in Microphone, version Unknown Version, Built-in Output, version Unknown Version, Port Built-in Microphone, version Unknown Version, Port Built-in Output, version Unknown Version]
```

Output for Safari:

```
Mixer data: [Default Audio Device, version Unknown Version, Built-in Output, version Unknown Version, Port Built-in Output, version Unknown Version]
```

Tested on two machines: `MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013), OS X Yosemite v. 10.10.2 (14C109), Safari - Version 8.0.3 (10600.3.18)`
and `iMac 27" late 2013 OS X v. 10.9.5, Safari - Version 7.1.3 (9537.85.12.18)`

What I have to do to make it work in Safari?
Thanks!